# Deleting unwanted New objects in the "add Object" menu

Tags: python

I've been coding a simple script to add an object to the `Add Panel'. But every time I click the run script button in the text editor it adds a new listing for the object. How can I can delete these unwanted listings so there's only one?

[image: Screenshot of the New objects]
Here is my script:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Add Polysphere",
    "author": "Johnson Martin",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 74, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Polysphere",
    "description": "Adds a new Polysphere",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh"}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector


def add_polysphere (self, context):
    scale_x = self.scale.x
    scale_y = self.scale.y

    verts = [(-0.8942768573760986, 0.0, 0.0), (-0.8221502304077148, 0.0, 0.3518523871898651), (-0.8221502304077148, 0.3518523871898651, 0.0), (-0.8221502304077148, 0.0, -0.3518523871898651), (-0.8221502304077148, -0.3518523871898651, 0.0), (-0.7653955817222595, -0.3270326554775238, 0.3270326554775238), (-0.7653955817222595, 0.3270326554775238, 0.3270326554775238), (-0.7653955817222595, 0.3270326554775238, -0.3270326554775238), (-0.7653955817222595, -0.3270326554775238, -0.3270326554775238), (0.0, 0.8942768573760986, 0.0), (0.0, 0.8221502304077148, 0.3518523871898651), (0.3518523871898651, 0.8221502304077148, 0.0), (0.0, 0.8221502304077148, -0.3518523871898651), (-0.3518523871898651, 0.8221502304077148, 0.0), (-0.3270326554775238, 0.7653955817222595, 0.3270326554775238), (0.3270326554775238, 0.7653955817222595, 0.3270326554775238), (0.3270326554775238, 0.7653955817222595, -0.3270326554775238), (-0.3270326554775238, 0.7653955817222595, -0.3270326554775238), (0.8942768573760986, 0.0, 0.0), (0.8221502304077148, 0.0, 0.3518523871898651), (0.8221502304077148, -0.3518523871898651, 0.0), (0.8221502304077148, 0.0, -0.3518523871898651), (0.8221502304077148, 0.3518523871898651, 0.0), (0.7653955817222595, 0.3270326554775238, 0.3270326554775238), (0.7653955817222595, -0.3270326554775238, 0.3270326554775238), (0.7653955817222595, -0.3270326554775238, -0.3270326554775238), (0.7653955817222595, 0.3270326554775238, -0.3270326554775238), (0.0, -0.8942768573760986, 0.0), (0.0, -0.8221502304077148, 0.3518523871898651), (-0.3518523871898651, -0.8221502304077148, 0.0), (0.0, -0.8221502304077148, -0.3518523871898651), (0.3518523871898651, -0.8221502304077148, 0.0), (0.3270326554775238, -0.7653955817222595, 0.3270326554775238), (-0.3270326554775238, -0.7653955817222595, 0.3270326554775238), (-0.3270326554775238, -0.7653955817222595, -0.3270326554775238), (0.3270326554775238, -0.7653955817222595, -0.3270326554775238), (0.0, 0.0, -0.8942768573760986), (-0.3518523871898651, 0.0, -0.8221502304077148), (0.0, 0.3518523871898651, -0.8221502304077148), (0.3518523871898651, 0.0, -0.8221502304077148), (0.0, -0.3518523871898651, -0.8221502304077148), (-0.3270326554775238, -0.3270326554775238, -0.7653955817222595), (-0.3270326554775238, 0.3270326554775238, -0.7653955817222595), (0.3270326554775238, 0.3270326554775238, -0.7653955817222595), (0.3270326554775238, -0.3270326554775238, -0.7653955817222595), (0.0, 0.0, 0.8942768573760986), (0.3518523871898651, 0.0, 0.8221502304077148), (0.0, 0.3518523871898651, 0.8221502304077148), (-0.3518523871898651, 0.0, 0.8221502304077148), (0.0, -0.3518523871898651, 0.8221502304077148), (0.3270326554775238, -0.3270326554775238, 0.7653955817222595), (0.3270326554775238, 0.3270326554775238, 0.7653955817222595), (-0.3270326554775238, 0.3270326554775238, 0.7653955817222595), (-0.3270326554775238, -0.3270326554775238, 0.7653955817222595), (-0.5956068634986877, -0.5956068634986877, -0.30039307475090027), (-0.6323491930961609, -0.6323491930961609, 0.0), (-0.5956068634986877, -0.5956068634986877, 0.30039307475090027), (-0.5956068634986877, -0.30039307475090027, 0.5956068634986877), (-0.6323491930961609, 0.0, 0.6323491930961609), (-0.5956068634986877, 0.30039307475090027, 0.5956068634986877), (-0.5956068634986877, 0.5956068634986877, 0.30039307475090027), (-0.6323491930961609, 0.6323491930961609, 0.0), (-0.5956068634986877, 0.5956068634986877, -0.30039307475090027), (-0.5956068634986877, 0.30039307475090027, -0.5956068634986877), (-0.6323491930961609, 0.0, -0.6323491930961609), (-0.5956068634986877, -0.30039307475090027, -0.5956068634986877), (-0.30039307475090027, 0.5956068634986877, 0.5956068634986877), (0.0, 0.6323491930961609, 0.6323491930961609), (0.30039307475090027, 0.5956068634986877, 0.5956068634986877), (0.5956068634986877, 0.5956068634986877, 0.30039307475090027), (0.6323491930961609, 0.6323491930961609, 0.0), (0.5956068634986877, 0.5956068634986877, -0.30039307475090027), (0.30039307475090027, 0.5956068634986877, -0.5956068634986877), (0.0, 0.6323491930961609, -0.6323491930961609), (-0.30039307475090027, 0.5956068634986877, -0.5956068634986877), (0.5956068634986877, 0.30039307475090027, 0.5956068634986877), (0.6323491930961609, 0.0, 0.6323491930961609), (0.5956068634986877, -0.30039307475090027, 0.5956068634986877), (0.5956068634986877, -0.5956068634986877, 0.30039307475090027), (0.6323491930961609, -0.6323491930961609, 0.0), (0.5956068634986877, -0.5956068634986877, -0.30039307475090027), (0.5956068634986877, -0.30039307475090027, -0.5956068634986877), (0.6323491930961609, 0.0, -0.6323491930961609), (0.5956068634986877, 0.30039307475090027, -0.5956068634986877), (0.30039307475090027, -0.5956068634986877, 0.5956068634986877), (0.0, -0.6323491930961609, 0.6323491930961609), (-0.30039307475090027, -0.5956068634986877, 0.5956068634986877), (-0.30039307475090027, -0.5956068634986877, -0.5956068634986877), (0.0, -0.6323491930961609, -0.6323491930961609), (0.30039307475090027, -0.5956068634986877, -0.5956068634986877), (-0.5163109302520752, -0.5163109302520752, -0.5163109302520752), (-0.5163109302520752, -0.5163109302520752, 0.5163109302520752), (-0.5163109302520752, 0.5163109302520752, -0.5163109302520752), (-0.5163109302520752, 0.5163109302520752, 0.5163109302520752), (0.5163109302520752, -0.5163109302520752, -0.5163109302520752), (0.5163109302520752, -0.5163109302520752, 0.5163109302520752), (0.5163109302520752, 0.5163109302520752, -0.5163109302520752), (0.5163109302520752, 0.5163109302520752, 0.5163109302520752)]
    edges = []
    faces = [(0, 4, 5, 1), (1, 5, 57, 58), (4, 55, 56, 5), (5, 56, 91, 57), (0, 1, 6, 2), (2, 6, 60, 61), (1, 58, 59, 6), (6, 59, 93, 60), (0, 2, 7, 3), (3, 7, 63, 64), (2, 61, 62, 7), (7, 62, 92, 63), (0, 3, 8, 4), (4, 8, 54, 55), (3, 64, 65, 8), (8, 65, 90, 54), (9, 13, 14, 10), (10, 14, 66, 67), (13, 61, 60, 14), (14, 60, 93, 66), (9, 10, 15, 11), (11, 15, 69, 70), (10, 67, 68, 15), (15, 68, 97, 69), (9, 11, 16, 12), (12, 16, 72, 73), (11, 70, 71, 16), (16, 71, 96, 72), (9, 12, 17, 13), (13, 17, 62, 61), (12, 73, 74, 17), (17, 74, 92, 62), (18, 22, 23, 19), (19, 23, 75, 76), (22, 70, 69, 23), (23, 69, 97, 75), (18, 19, 24, 20), (20, 24, 78, 79), (19, 76, 77, 24), (24, 77, 95, 78), (18, 20, 25, 21), (21, 25, 81, 82), (20, 79, 80, 25), (25, 80, 94, 81), (18, 21, 26, 22), (22, 26, 71, 70), (21, 82, 83, 26), (26, 83, 96, 71), (27, 31, 32, 28), (28, 32, 84, 85), (31, 79, 78, 32), (32, 78, 95, 84), (27, 28, 33, 29), (29, 33, 56, 55), (28, 85, 86, 33), (33, 86, 91, 56), (27, 29, 34, 30), (30, 34, 87, 88), (29, 55, 54, 34), (34, 54, 90, 87), (27, 30, 35, 31), (31, 35, 80, 79), (30, 88, 89, 35), (35, 89, 94, 80), (36, 40, 41, 37), (37, 41, 65, 64), (40, 88, 87, 41), (41, 87, 90, 65), (36, 37, 42, 38), (38, 42, 74, 73), (37, 64, 63, 42), (42, 63, 92, 74), (36, 38, 43, 39), (39, 43, 83, 82), (38, 73, 72, 43), (43, 72, 96, 83), (36, 39, 44, 40), (40, 44, 89, 88), (39, 82, 81, 44), (44, 81, 94, 89), (45, 49, 50, 46), (46, 50, 77, 76), (49, 85, 84, 50), (50, 84, 95, 77), (45, 46, 51, 47), (47, 51, 68, 67), (46, 76, 75, 51), (51, 75, 97, 68), (45, 47, 52, 48), (48, 52, 59, 58), (47, 67, 66, 52), (52, 66, 93, 59), (45, 48, 53, 49), (49, 53, 86, 85), (48, 58, 57, 53), (53, 57, 91, 86)]

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="New Polysphere")
    mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
    # useful for development when the mesh may be invalid.
    # mesh.validate(verbose=True)
    object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=self)


class OBJECT_OT_add_polysphere(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Polysphere"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_polysphere"
    bl_label = "Add New Polysphere"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    scale = FloatVectorProperty(
            name="scale",
            default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
            subtype='TRANSLATION',
            description="scaling",
            )

    def execute(self, context):

        add_polysphere(self, context)

        return {'FINISHED'}


# Registration

def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(OBJECT_OT_add_polysphere.bl_idname,text="Add Polysphere",icon='MESH_UVSPHERE')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_polysphere)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_polysphere)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I think you need to run the unregister function you made somehow....

Comment: @GiantCowFilms How Would I do that? I'm pretty new to Python. :P

Comment: I've never used it either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, just hit <kbd>F8</kbd> in this case that will refresh the python environment.

[image]

Comment: Ah, Thank you! I figured it was something like that.

Comment: It doesn't work (atleast in Blender 2.8-3.0)! Any other ideas?