# How to remove menu item which added multiple times

Tags: python, add-on

I am working on a plugin. Unfortunately my unregister() function attempted to remove the menu function from a wrong menu.
Now the result is when I load and enable the plugin and open up the menu I see my entry multiple times.
Here is my register and unregister functions:

```
def register():
    register_class(TunnelGen)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_curve_specials.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    for i in range(10): # the menu is registered accidentally multiple times
        bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_curve_specials.remove(menu_func)
    unregister_class(TunnelGen)
```

How can I fix the menu?

Comment: Have you hit F8 yet and restarted the addon / or blender ?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/deleting-unwanted-new-objects-in-the-add-object-menu/30386#30386

Comment: I didn't try to restart blender yet. I will.